# Embedded Helvetica Bold is rendering ugly

Tags: css, font-face, embedding

I couldn't get @font-face to work within a jsfiddle, so I just have a picture, to show you. This is how Helvetica Bold renders for me in every browser:

[image]

I uploaded it to my server and embedded it this way:

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/28cb34");

@font-face{
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueCE-Bold';
    src: url('http://www.sebastianstarke.com/portfolio/wp-content/themes/protofolio/font/28CB34_0_0.eot');
    src: url('http://www.sebastianstarke.com/portfolio/wp-content/themes/protofolio/font/28CB34_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.sebastianstarke.com/portfolio/wp-content/themes/protofolio/font/28CB34_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.sebastianstarke.com/portfolio/wp-content/themes/protofolio/font/28CB34_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

The page in question is this one: http://www.sebastianstarke.com/portfolio/

In the example file, that came with the font it looks the same, but my client says, on his computer (A Mac) it looks OK. I'm using Windows, the font is from myfonts. I got it from my client, he says, he bought it a few weeks ago.

Comment: What operating system are you using, and where did you get the Helvetica Neue fonts from? I tried copying them off of my Mac onto my Linux computer, and I got the same thing. I think it might have to do with some copyright thing Apple put on its fonts.

Comment: The website probably looks fine on his computer because he already has Helvetica Neue installed, so it just uses the installed font instead of your font. If you remove all references to the name "Helvetica Neue" (i.e. call your font something else in the `@font-face`), does it still look good on your client's computer?

Comment: You sure you're not just setting it at a font-size that renders oddly? Try inspecting in dev tools and se if moving the font-size up or down by one smooths that out. Not the first time I've seen this, BTW.

Comment: I removed the reference to Helvetica Neue, that makes no difference. In the meantime, I tested it on another Windows computer. It looks odd there, but not on the Mac. Font Size does not make a real difference. It looks odd for everything under about 28px/1.8em. Sometimes less odd and sometimes more, depending on the size, but never perfect. On Linotypes website, you can test Helvetica. It looks brilliant for me on every size.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with Helvetica in Chrome in Windows PC:

```
    <h1 style="font-size:41px;font-weight:700;font-family:Helvetica">
    Your aktu Will Fiskeshop aktakakak
    </h1>
```

https://codepen.io/TheJesper/pen/vYXNgaV

[image: Helvetica with corrupt alignement]

I solved it by uninstalling all local versions of the font. Maybe you have a local copy of the font that don't quite matches your preferred style (font-size, font-weight, font-style).

➡ Try and uninstall this font completely (both Helvetica and Helvetica Neue) and restart your computer. I had to use **Delete.On.Boot** since it was in use:

https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/delete_on_reboot.html

In this way your computer will "match" the setup of most Windows users. The Mac version of the font is pre-installed and should work smoothly for Mac Users...

If this doesn't help you, then try to find another version of the Helvetica Neue Web font and see if there are any difference. On fonts.com you can enter your own custom text:

https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/neue-helvetica